# What justifies assuming that a level surface contains a differentiable curve?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

My textbook's proof that the Lagrange multiplier method is valid begins:

> Let $X(t)$ be a differentiable curve on the surface $S$ passing through $P$

Where $S$ is the level surface defining the constraint, and $P$ is an extremum of the function that we're seeking to optimize. But how do we know that such a curve exists?

$S$ is specifically defined as the set of points in the (open) domain of the continuously differentiable function $g$ with $g(X) = 0$ but $\operatorname{grad}g(X)\ne0$. The function $f$ that we're seeking to optimize is assumed to be continuously differentiable and defined on the same open domain as $g$, and $P$ is an extremum of $f$ on $S$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the Implicit Function Theorem, near $P$ you can represent your level surface as a graph, say $z=\phi(x,y)$, where $\phi$ is continuously differentiable. If $P=\phi(a,b)$, take any line through $(a,b)$ and you get a nice curve.

Comment: Thanks, I'll think of this when I learn about the IFT. My book hasn't covered that yet, though - is there another way?

Comment: No, honestly. In most multivariable calculus courses, we wave our hands wildly at such questions :) And, unless you're taking a somewhat theoretical course, you won't see the Implicit Function Theorem until later in your mathematical life. :)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "represent a level surface as a graph". Could you be more explicit as to the nature of the function $\phi$? What is its domain/range? What is the relationship between its input and output?

Comment: For example, the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ can be represented as a graph of $z=\phi(x,y)=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ near the point $P=(0,0,1)$. $\phi$ will map some open set in $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$. The size of the open set depends on the nature of your function $g$. For my example, you will have the open unit disk $\{x^2+y^2<1\}\subset\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: My mistake. In that case I don't know a more accessible answer for you than Ted's, though here's my try: the fact that $S$ is a level surface does not matter. Through any point $p$ on any regular surface $M$ and for any vector $v$ tangent to $M$ at $p$, there is a differentiable curve $\alpha$ on $M$ passing through $p$ with $\alpha'(0)=v$. But this is still just a special case of Ted's answer.

Comment: @proximal: The issue, of course, is to justify why a level surface with $\nabla g\ne 0$ is in fact a "regular surface" or $2$-dimensional manifold.

Comment: @proximal Could you bring back your answer? It seemed interesting to me and I think it would be a good idea to leave it if only for future readers.

Comment: @TedShifrin So strictly speaking $P=(a, b, \phi(a, b))$ ?

Comment: Jack, yes, absitively. @proximal would need to rewrite his answer in terms of a local smooth parametrization, which you don't necessarily know exists. From my set-up, it would be $\Phi(x,y)=(x,y,\phi(x,y))$.

Comment: @JackM I would have to decline; Ted is absolutely correct here, and I don't want to mislead anyone.